# Quick Fourier Series Question about Cn Integration

Tags: fourier-series

If I am given a function

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            2 & \quad x \in (0,6) \\0 & \quad x\in(0,-6)
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

$I=(-6,6)$

and I want to find the complex series representation, is it correct that

$\mathbb{C}_n=\frac{1}{12} \int_0^6(2*\exp(-\frac{-xni\pi}{12})) dx$?

Because the first half of interval contribution would just be $0$, Right?

To The MODERATOR  .. I am not fully sure about it, but hope it improves upon earlier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex Fourier series is defined as:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{i n x \frac{2 \pi}{L}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
c_n=\frac{1}{L} \int_{0}^{L} f(x) e^{-i n x \frac{2 \pi}{L}} dx
\end{equation}
In your case $L=3$. Of course the Fourier series is periodic.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, I thought $c_n=\frac{1}{2L}...$. How do you calculate L to begin with?

Comment: f(x) is different from zero only between 0 and 3. If you have 2L instead of L, your integral should be between -L and L, and you should have f(x)  defined between -L and L.

Comment: Not the definition of f(x) is much better. With this definition your integral computed between -6 and +6 reduces to an integral between 0 and 6, since your function is 0 between -6 and 0. Your $c_n$ is correct.

Comment: OK, I think I understood. Thank your for taking the time, Upax!